# Is connecting to a SSAS cube from SSRS server different than connecting to a SQL DB?

Tags: reporting-services, permissions, ssas, datasource, ssms

We have a service account that we use to store the credentials on our report server to connect to our SQL DB. We have had no issues with this. It connects fine. However, there is a SSAS cube on the same server as the DB. We try to connect to the cube with the same service account. This has been unsuccessful. The account is an admin on the cube. It is not assigned to any other role. The error I am getting is

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
      - Cannot impersonate user for data source 'Cube'.
      (rsErrorImpersonatingUser)
         - Log on failed. (rsLogonFailed)

It mentions to check username/password but I know they are right. Is connecting to a cube somehow different from connecting to a DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the technical details but we connect to our cubes differently that the SQL Server DBs.

We use service accounts and passwords to connect to SQL DBs but for our cubes, we **Use Windows Authentication** for credentials. Not sure what the rhyme or reason is but that's how we got it to work.